# Doctrine DBAL DELETE success or not

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dbal

How do I know if the DBAL DELETE was a success or not?

If for example I try to delete something which doesn't exist, how would I know? Do I have to do a query first to see if it exists or does the DBALs delete-function have any built-in system for that?

Here's my query:

```
$this->conn->delete('mytable', 
               array('mytableID'   => $id, 
                     'othercolumn' => $value['data']));
```

Now if the `$value['data']` is something that doesn't exist in the database, what does the DBAL actually do?

**Edit**:
I tried this:

```
$returnvalue = $this->conn->delete('mytable', 
                   array('mytableID'   => $id, 
                         'othercolumn' => $value['data']));
```

But the value is null.

**Edit2**:
Ah man.. I had other bug in my code. Delete DOES return a value for it, but it never got to my logger. `$returnvalue` is 0 when it fails to delete something.

Comment: Check the return value of the delete method

Comment: @Matteo: It's null. Nothing. Nada.

Comment: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.1/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Connection.html#_delete

Comment: Seems reurn an integer of the affected row numbers

Comment: @Matteo: Yeah I just updated my answer. It was my bad all along. Thanks for the help and sorry for my inability to read my own code! :) If you make your answer a real one, I'll make it an accepted one!